# Why do the free electrons in N-type want to diffuse?

Tags: electrons, charge, semiconductor-physics, diffusion

I'm trying to understand how a diode works and for this I've used(among other resources) the book written by Albert Malvino, *Electronic Principles*.

Everywhere I read about this topic, it says that when the N-type and P-type semiconductors are joined together, the free electrons from the N-type diffuse to the P-type.

**I don't understand why is the diffusion happening.**

The book *Electronic Principles* contains an attempt to explain this and states that the electrons diffuse because they have the same charge and they repel each other, but in my understanding the P-type and the **N-type** semiconductors have a neutral charge, because the number of positive charges (**protons** in the nuclei) is equal to the number of negative charges (**free electrons** and **covalent bonds electrons**), so the electrons repeling each other can't actually be the cause of the diffusion.

Comment: They are always diffusing - they are free electrons and can and do execute random diffusive movement all the time. Fields will add a drift component, but diffusion is always going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in a thermodynamic argument. The diffusion is a spontaneous process that occurs when particles with random motions are not uniformly distributed. The electrons in the 
conduction band in the n region are much more numerous that in the p junction. They will naturally tend to balance the concentration from the n junction to the p junction since the equilibrium tends to be the state with maximum disorder ie maximum entropy.

A good visual picture of how the diffusion process occurs is in this video at 4'50.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBtEckh3L9Q

So the answer to what causes diffusion is thermal motion of quasi free electrons.

Answer (score 1):

A book on semiconductor devices in general, [like this one](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/contents.htm) (e.g. section 2.7), may help. Also, just look at the diagram at the right of [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor#Physics_of_semiconductors).

In general, imagine that we're looking at a graph of different energies (usually shown on the $y$ axis) in this semiconductor. The big thing that you'll notice in a semiconductor is that the *density of states* $n(E)$ contains a *band gap* between the "valence" and "conduction" bands. In general, doping can introduce new states and thus modify those bands<sup>(1)</sup>, but the general wisdom is that, with weak doping, mostly what you do is modify the density of electrons without changing $n(E)$ too much. Changing the number of electrons that there are means what? Changing the *Fermi energy*, which is the average energy to add new electrons to the system. This can change the majority charge carriers; see for example the chart at the bottom of [this explanation of Fermi energies](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-Delhi/Semiconductor%20Devices/LMB2A/2b.htm).

Basically the problem is that the new electrons that the $n$-type dopant introduces need<sup>(2)</sup> occupy higher-energy states in the conduction band. The $p$-type dopant introduces holes which suck up some of its own higher-energy states, so its electrons similarly occupy lower-energy states.

Well, what happens if you've got two semiconductors in contact with different Fermi levels? Higher energies are occupied on the left than the right, and what happens? Answer: some of the higher-energy electrons on the left "fall into" the lower-energy states on the right. Yes, this leaves a $+$ charge on the $n$-type side and a $-$ charge on the $p$-type side with an associated voltage. That voltage actually has a name; it's called the "diode drop", and I believe in silicon it's pretty consistently about 0.6 V. The result: on the right hand side all of your valence band is filled in; on your left hand side none of your conduction band remains, and you've got a "depletion region". But the Fermi energy isn't just some abstract thing that we have no access to; we can raise or lower it by shifting the voltages that either side is at.<sup>(3)</sup> Basically if you use a little voltage to counteract the difference in their intrinsic Fermi energies, then you return back to a current-carrying configuration, after you go above the diode drop -- this is why diodes work the way they do (no current under reverse bias or zero bias, but a current once you overcome the 0.6V diode drop).

**Footnotes**

1. [Here's a fun *Nature* article](http://www.nature.com/nmat/journal/v8/n5/box/nmat2425_BX2.html) simulating some of those changes of $n(E)$ with increasing doping.
2. They only "need" to do this on average. Thermal jitters "smear" out the occupations a bit, but on averaging the higher Fermi energy means higher-energy states tend to be occupied.
3. This is the parameter $\mu$ that you always see in the FD function; it is the "chemical potential" of the electrons.